# PHP regex and adjacent capturing groups

Tags: php, regex, string, backreference, camelcasing

I'm using capturing groups in regular expressions for the first time and I'm wondering what my problem is, as I assume that the regex engine looks through the string left-to-right.

I'm trying to convert an UpperCamelCase string into a hyphened-lowercase-string, so for example:

```
HelloWorldThisIsATest => hello-world-this-is-a-test
```

My precondition is an alphabetic string, so I don't need to worry about numbers or other characters. Here is what I tried:

```php
mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/([A-Za-z])([A-Z])/', '$1-$2', "HelloWorldThisIsATest"));
```

The result:

```
hello-world-this-is-atest
```

This is almost what I want, except there should be a hyphen between `a` and `test`. I've already included `A-Z` in my first capturing group so I would assume that the engine sees `AT` and hyphenates that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about `"HelloWorldHTMLTest"`? Should that become `"hello-world-html-test"` or `"hello-world-h-t-m-l-test"`?

Comment: @Jack Interesting use case I haven't thought of… I'd say the first one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The Reason your Regex will Not Work: Overlapping Matches**

- Your regex matches `sA` in `IsATest`, allowing you to insert a `-` between the `s` and the `A`
- In order to insert a `-` between the `A` and the `T`, the regex would have to match `AT`.
- This is impossible because the `A` is already matched as part of `sA`. You cannot have overlapping matches in direct regex.
- Is all hope lost? No! **This is a perfect situation for lookarounds.**

**Do it in Two Easy Lines**

Here's the easy way to do it with regex:

```
$regex = '~(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[A-Z])~';
echo strtolower(preg_replace($regex,"-","HelloWorldThisIsATest"));
```

See the output at the bottom of the [php demo](http://ideone.com/iy9eTc):

> Output: `hello-world-this-is-a-test`

Will add explanation in a moment. :)

- The regex doesn't match any characters. Rather, it targets positions in the string: the positions between the change in letter case. To do so, it uses a lookbehind and a lookahead
- The `(?<=[a-zA-Z])` lookbehind asserts that what precedes the current position is a letter
- The `(?=[A-Z])` lookahead asserts that what follows the current position is an upper-case letter.
- We just replace these positions with a `-`, and convert the lot to lowercase.

If you look carefully on this [regex101 screen](http://regex101.com/r/eD0jT7), you can see lines between the words, where the regex matches.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: The reason your regex cannot work is that it would need to allow consecutive matches. Will add an explanation for this in a moment. You **must** use lookarounds as in my answer.

Comment: Your question said `I'm wondering what my problem is`... My answer actually provides an explanation.

Comment: I like your answer too as it provides an explanation as to why my regex didn't work.

Comment: your regex will match only two alphabets.

Comment: @AvinashRaj See my demo. :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks, I know you're a regex scholar—this is the best solution for this kind of problem (zero-width match.)

Answer (score 5):

I've separated the two regular expressions for simplicity:

```
preg_replace(array('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '/([A-Z]+)([A-Z])/'), '$1-$2', $string);
```

It processes the string twice to find:

1. lowercase -> uppercase boundaries
2. multiple uppercase letters followed by another uppercase letter

This will have the following behaviour:

```
ThisIsHTMLTest -> This-Is-HTML-Test
ThisIsATest    -> This-Is-A-Test
```

Alternatively, use a look-ahead assertion (this will effect the reuse of the last capital letter that was used in the previous match):

```
preg_replace('/([A-Z]+|[a-z]+)(?=[A-Z])/', '$1-', $string);
```

Comment: `+1`, good and clear solution, also solves the use case of multiple upper case abbreviations

Comment: Are we sure there are not cases where due to the character arrangement, we wouldn't need three passes?... Or more...? I have a hunch that this might be the case.

Comment: +1 as it covers use cases that might apply to me in the future, also a good solution

Comment: @zx81 Although technically possible, with title cased names the acronyms you're using will be exclusively in uppercase.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Btw, I've managed to squeeze it all into one regular expression :)

Comment: Mmm, not so sure... It seems to me that with the first pass, the string gets expanded by an arbitrary nubmer of `-`, which could be odd or even... Therefore, two positions that were missed on pass one might end up with different parities. But my intuition could be wrong, I haven't stopped to work it out on paper.

Comment: @zx81 Let me when you have; I'd be interested to see if there are cases that "fail" on it.

Comment: Hey Jack, IMO the best way to know for sure would be to run a test on a file with random sequences. Don't have time for it, but I took a Wikipedia article, removed the `[^a-zA-Z]+` and ran the two replacements. As you had guessed, there were quite a number of two or three upper-case ones left, none of the others. Would be worth trying on a larger sample as in normal text there are not that many case switches. See you another time! :)

Answer (score 4):

To fix the interesting use case Jack mentioned in your comments (avoid splitting of abbreviations), I went with zx81's route of using lookahead and lookbehinds.

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])
```

You can split it in two for the explanation:

#### First part

```
(?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
  [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
)                        end of look-behind
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
)                        end of look-ahead
```

(TL;DR: Match between strings of the CamelCase Pattern.)

#### Second part

```
(?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
  [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
)                        end of look-behind
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
  [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
)                        end of look-ahead
```

(TL;DR: Special case, match between abbreviation and CamelCase pattern)

So your code would then be:

```
mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])/', '-', "HelloWorldThisIsATest"));
```

## [Demo of matches](http://rubular.com/r/2ssBwuWkCv)

## [Demo of code](http://ideone.com/r1EqCY)

Comment: I was just about to comment asking for an explanation when I saw that the post was edited! Thank you, this is what I am looking for. I'll accept the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: They're all good answers but I'd have to accept the other one because it provided an explanation to the first part of my question.